# SpeechSynthesis API for Chinese -- Firefox

Tags: javascript, html, firefox, text-to-speech

The [SpeechSynthesis API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SpeechSynthesis) does not speak Mandarin on Firefox. Is it not supported? I couldn't find a list in the docs. I tried several different language [tags](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/bcp/bcp47.txt).

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nhztka2n/):

```
var msg = new SpeechSynthesisUtterance();
msg.text = '你好';
msg.lang = 'zh';
window.speechSynthesis.speak(msg);
```

(You should hear "nihao" if it works. It sounds *fine* on Chrome and *OK* on Safari. On Firefox 53.0.2 on Ubuntu, I hear "letter letter".)

Comment: I tested your fiddle and it works well in Firefox 53 on Mac 10.12

Comment: On Ubuntu, there is no Chinese on `speechSynthesis.getVoices().map((el) => el.lang).sort()`; but it speaks fine on Chrome on Ubuntu.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On Windows, Firefox has only 3 voices, all English.

I wrote a jsbin showing a browser's voices:
https://jsbin.com/ginanegoqu/edit?js,output

```
if ('speechSynthesis' in window) {
    // Start an html table for languages details
    var text = '<table border=1><tr><th>Default<th>Language<th>Local<th>Name<th>URI</tr>';
    // Get voices; add to table markup
    function loadVoices() {
        var voices = speechSynthesis.getVoices();
        voices.forEach(function(voice, i) {
          // Add all details to table
          text += '<tr><td>' + voice.default + '<td>'
              + voice.lang + '<td>' + voice.localService
              + '<td>' + voice.name + '<td>' + voice.voiceURI;
        });
    }
    loadVoices();
    langList.innerHTML = text;
    // Chrome loads voices asynchronously.
    window.speechSynthesis.onvoiceschanged = function(e) {
        loadVoices();
        langList.innerHTML = text;
    }
}
```